# Regular expression to match multiple numbers in a sentence where said numbers are sometimes omitted

Tags: regex

Given the sentences below, how do I match all numbers specified by "Run time", and optionally match just the "Run time" numbers instead of what's on the rest of the page (see example 3):

Example 1:

> Run Time: 72 hours, 14 minutes, and 20 seconds

Example 2 (only two numbers, singular seconds):

> Run Time: 28 minutes, and 1 second

Example 3 (only seconds but numbers further down not interested in them):

> Run Time:
>
> 24 seconds
>
> This notice is the result of a request from “cPanel Backup System”.
>
> The system generated this notice on Thursday, July 28, 2022

The closest match so far but doesn't work:

```
/Run Time: (\d+) hour.+(\d+) minute.+(\d+) second/
```

That matches the 72, but only the 4 and 0 of 14 and 20.

I'm using this tool to test:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: Would hours, minutes, and seconds _always_ be appearing together, in CSV format as shown above?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen thanks for asking. The output that appears to be CSV is actually a sentence output from a WHM/cPanel backup. The sentence varies, but could be shorter for example: `Run Time: 51 minutes and 20 seconds` . I've accepted @wu denny's answer because it's semi perfect, but modified it and added questions marks to cater for this optionality:

`[^0-9]+(\d+)?[^0-9]+(\d+)?[^0-9]+(\d+)`

Comment: Your pattern should be non greedy `Run Time: (\d+) hour.+?(\d+) minute.+?(\d+) second` https://regex101.com/r/EoNykQ/1

Answer (score 2):

Exclude the number and capture them

```
[^0-9]+(\d+)[^0-9]+(\d+)[^0-9]+(\d+)
```